# Slow file copying in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: files, copy

After a clean start with no other programs running it takes about 10 mS to copy a 10 MB file between two directories on the same disk. After about an hour running various FORTRAN programs it sometimes takes about 5 S (ie 500 times longer) to copy the same file. It is not a sudden jump but several smaller jumps. Can anyone  give me an indication of what may be wrong.

Comment: @davd, what are the FORTRAN programs doing? Are they writing a lot of data, that might be occupying the buffers and/or keeping write processes to the drive busy?

Comment: You can install `iotop` and run it with `sudo iotop -o` to monitor the read and write operations to disk.

Comment: How *exactly* are you copying the file? How did you measure the duration? What's running in the background when you copy the file? Anything that might access the (same) storage? What's the memory pressure at the time (check the output of `free -h`)? On what medium is the swap space located? That is its access delay time and data throughput? Is it the same storage medium as the one holding the file in question?

Comment: The programs are my own and they do a faiir bit of file work.

Comment: I will try iotop. The timing was with no other programs running an "time cp x y"